# Dell 7430 - no sound from speakers - HDA-Intel" Realtek ALC289 - Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, dell

almost giving up - new laptop has no sound from speakers.
They show as playing, but I hear nothing.
Dell Latitude 7430, 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1270P × 16.

tal@tal-Latitude-7430:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x6055290000 irq 207
```

tal@tal-Latitude-7430:~$ ls -ld /proc/asound/cards

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 okt 28 22:06 /proc/asound/cards
```

tal@tal-Latitude-7430:~$ lspci -vnn | grep -A 1 -i audio

```
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Dell Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [1028:0b0b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 207, IOMMU group 14
```

speaker-test runs infinitely without sound (there are subtle clicks).

tal@tal-Latitude-7430:~$ aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC289 Analog [ALC289 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

tal@tal-Latitude-7430:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -E 'snd'

```
[    4.785286] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.791690] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.792811] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.826162] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC289: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.826166] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.826168] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.826169] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.826170] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.826170] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
[    4.826171] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1b
[    4.826172] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
```

I saw a lot of patches in
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c?h=v6.0.5

So I installed `mainline` and installed Linux Kernel 6.0.5 (latest).

Nothing. Please help?

Comment: You may want to report this as a bug. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: Please, anything new? I am facing similar issue with Lenovo Yoga + 12700H Intel. I am running PopOS, the solution at bottom of https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/ did help to get sound working, but not microphone.

Comment: Sorry everyone - I had a Dell technician over (I have company support) and he replaced the speaker in less than 10 minutes. Turns out there is a hardware self test in the BIOS so I could have saved hours of my life.